# How to create a n array tree from a MultiIndexed pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` dataframe. I had called `set_index` method on multiple columns.

Could you please help me in building the same dataframe.

```
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly'], 
    'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson'], 
    'age': [42, 52, ] 
    'preTestScore': [4, 24],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])

df1 = df.set_index(['first_name','last_name','age'])
```

Then there will be four columns. First will be indexed column and other will be 
    pretestScore  and postTestScore

```
first_name-second_name-age     preTestScore            postTestScore

Jason
        Miller
                  42
                                 4                           25
 Molly
        Jacob
                  52              
                                 24                          94
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I have made some edits to the question.That will answer your question

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want the index to be combination of those columns but then you want that to appear in one column, for which there is no pandas function from what I searched through. Custom way of building that will be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly'], 
    'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson'], 
    'age': [42, 52, ],
    'preTestScore': [4, 24],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(raw_data)
df['first_name-last_name-age'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['first_name']+' '+ row['last_name']+' '+str(row['age']), axis=1)
df = df.set_index(['first_name-last_name-age'])
df = df.drop('first_name', axis=1)
df = df.drop('last_name', axis=1)
df = df.drop('age', axis=1)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
```

Output of the above is as expected by you:

```
  first_name-last_name-age  postTestScore  preTestScore
0          Jason Miller 42             25             4
1        Molly Jacobson 52             94            24
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks , but I wanted to create narray tree

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by `narray tree` ?